# Using topology to show that a certain polynomial has a root

Tags: general-topology

How exactly is it possible to use topology to show that every polynomial $f(x)= x^3 + ax^2 + bx +c$ has a root in $\mathbb{R}$? How about for a root in $\mathbb{C}$? I had no idea that topology had applications here!

Comment: The fundamental theorem of algebra can b proved by topology (e.g., calculation of a suitable fundamental group).  If you just google fundamental theorem of algebra topology then you'll find several useful pages, the first one being the Wikipedia page on the fund. thm. of algebra with a section called "topological proofs".  The next hit will probably be a Mathoverflow page with lots of different proofs, including several that are from topology.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using the intermediate value theorem. This comes from the topological result that the image of a (path-)connected set under a continuous function is (path)-connected.

Pick a large positive $x$ and a large negative $x$ and see what happens.

This real root is also a complex root.

Comment: Could you please elaborate?

Comment: @Sachin What is the behaviour $f(x)$ as $x\rightarrow\pm\infty$?

Comment: $f(x) \rightarrow \infty$ as $x \rightarrow \infty$, and $f(x) \rightarrow -\infty$ as $x \rightarrow -\infty$.

Comment: @Sachin Correct. That means for a large enough $N\in\mathbb{R}$ you have $f(N)>0$. Similarly for a large enough $-M\in\mathbb{R}$ you have $f(-M)<0$. Do you know the intermediate value theorem? $f$ is continuous on the closed interval $[-M,N]$ and $f(-M)<0<f(N)$...

Comment: Yes. I remember learning it from old-school calculus.

Comment: @Sachin So... essentially $f$ goes from negative to positive so it must cut the $x$-axis.